# How to create import option for xml

Tags: import, xml

I want to put in theme admin page an option for *demo content* XML.

This option should offer the possibility to switch between Demo Content and Default WordPress installation content. If I select *demo*, I want to show Demo content from my XML file. If select *default* I want to show what I have already posted, not the imported XML content.

Answer (score 0):

Sound like an interesting, but I think it would be very difficult, because *content* is more than just posts:

- Post authors for the demo content must match existing users.
- Taxonomies (tags, categories, nav menus) are bound to existing content.
- Comments need proper associations with post IDs and post types.

One way to do what you want:

- Create copies of the existing tables (posts, post_meta, comments, taxonomy tables) with a different prefix.
- Filter `query` and replace the table names when you want to show the demo content.
- During import, map existing users to the new content.

There are probably a billion ways how this can break. Multi-site and unusual database setups are obvious. :)